# How to use kotlin style in mockMvc?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-mvc, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

I have classical style test with mockMvc and it works:

```
    val result = mockMvc.perform(
        post(path)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(groupCreateDto)),
    ).andExpect(status().isBadRequest)
        .andReturn()
```

I've met [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/mockmvc/authentication.html) that Kotlin has a specific style and I've decide to rewrite:

```
val result = mockMvc.post(path) {
    contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
    content = content().string(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(groupCreateDto))
}.andExpect { status{isBadRequest()} }
    .andReturn()
```

But it doesn't work with error:

```
2023-10-03T13:19:34.536+03:00 ERROR 17912 --- [    Test worker] ***.RestExceptionHandler   : JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'org': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /api/v1/groups
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json", Content-Length:"106"]
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = ****.MyGroupController
           Method = ****.MyGroupController#createGroup(GroupCreateRequestDto)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 500
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json"]
     Content type = application/json
             Body = {"code":500,"reason":"JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'org': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')"}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

BRW I don't have org in a string generated by `objectMapper.writeValueAsString(groupCreateDto)`
Any ideas ?

Comment: Why did you use `content = content().string(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(groupCreateDto))` instead of `content = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(groupCreateDto)`?

Comment: @k314159
 now it works. Thank you!

Comment: @k314159 do you want to post an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by this line in the Kotlin translation:

```
content = content().string(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(groupCreateDto))
```

It should be just

```
content = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(groupCreateDto)
```

The latter code would reflect the same line from the original code. On the other hand, the `content().string...` construct creates a `RequestMatcher`, which is not what you want as you're not in the asserting part of the code at this point.